# Between en createdCriteria no funciona

Tags: java, grails, groovy, criteria

Tengo un problema muy raro. He creado 3 entidades de esta manera:

```
CCB ccb1 = new Ccb(1)
CCB ccb2 = new Ccb(2)
CCB ccb3 = new Ccb(3)
```

Donde el parametro pasado es el ID del objeto.

Luego, cuando creo una lista con la clausula between, esta es creada con size = 0, sin elementos:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> ccbIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(
            Ccb.createCriteria().list {
                between("id", 1, 5)
                projections {
                    id()
                }
            }
    )
```

Probe con la siguiente alternativa pero es lo mismo:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> ccbIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(
            Ccb.createCriteria().list {
                between("id", "1", "5")
                projections {
                    id()
                }
            }
    )
```

Lo increible es que si en vez de la clausula between utilizo la eq:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> ccbIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(
            Ccb.createCriteria().list {
                eq("id", 2)
                projections {
                    id()
                }
            }
    )
```

La lista me devuelve el elemento con id 2!
No puedo entender donde esta el error.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Lo haz probado con los [where querys](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#whereQueries)? Son parecidos a los createCriteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de ejecutar un sin fin de pruebas, llegué a la conclusión de que es un error en Grails cuando se usa el almacenamiento H2. Con SQL funciona bien.